# How to extend RetryRegistry bean in resilience4j [Spring Boot]?

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

I'm using Spring Boot to configure `Retry`, I configured some of `Retry` instances in YML file but because I can't find option how to calculate `IntervalFuntion` I want to config some instances in `@Configuration` file, and I have been lost.

```
  @Bean
  public Retry customRetryConfigCustomizer() {
    RetryConfig config = RetryConfig.custom()
        .intervalFunction(IntervalFunction.ofExponentialBackoff(2000L, 1.75d))
        .maxAttempts(10)
        .retryExceptions(WebClientRequestException.class)
        .build();
    Retry.of(SOME_CLIENT_INSTANCE, config);
    return RetryRegistry.ofDefaults().retry(SOME_CLIENT_INSTANCE, config);
  }
```

I think `Retry` configurates but it hasn't been added into `RetryRegistry` that spring uses in his `@Retry` annotations, and I don't know what am I missing. Also I don't want to use `RetryConfigCustomizer` because in that option first I have to create instance in YML file then I can change it.

So I repeat my question:

Is there a way to extend `RetryRegistry` that is configured in YML file and creates `Retry` in configuration file?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I needed to add logging https://stackoverflow.com/a/66883879/1460643

Comment: I did it everything by Spring config file
 `  resilience4j.retry:
    instances:
      webClient:
        maxAttempts: 4
        waitDuration: 2s
        enableExponentialBackoff: true
        exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 2
        retryExceptions:
          - org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestExceptio`